# Replication server crash - > 18:39:32 UTC - mysqld got signal 11

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, mysql5.5

Below you can see the part of the log showing the crash. The replication server is 5.6 and the master 5.5 but this setup has worked with warnings for the last week or so.
Now, after trying to change some user permissions, the replication server crashed and won't load again. Any ideas on where to start?

> 18:39:32 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ; This could be because you hit a
>   bug. It is also possible that this binary or one of the libraries it
>   was linked against is corrupt, improperly built, or misconfigured.
>   This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware. We will try
>   our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help diagnose the
>   problem, but since we have already crashed,  something is definitely
>   wrong and this may fail.
>
> key_buffer_size=262144 read_buffer_size=524288 max_used_connections=1
>   max_threads=200 thread_count=2 connection_count=0 It is possible that
>   mysqld could use up to  key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size +
>   sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 156591 K  bytes of memory Hope that's
>   ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
>
> Thread pointer: 0x7fb01c000990 Attempting backtrace. You can use the
>   following information to find out where mysqld died. If you see no
>   messages after this, something went terribly wrong... stack_bottom =
>   7fb0387649f0 thread_stack 0x40000
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x20)[0x83f710]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x34d)[0x61fbbd]
>   /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x11240)[0x7fb2739b9240]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x641849]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z17mysql_create_userP3THDR4ListI11st_lex_userE+0x25d)[0x6467bd]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x201c)[0x68cc1c]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state+0x328)[0x691858]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN15Query_log_event14do_apply_eventEPK14Relay_log_infoPKcj+0xc75)[0x7e5e95]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN9Log_event11apply_eventEP14Relay_log_info+0x6b)[0x7e3ecb]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z26apply_event_and_update_posPP9Log_eventP3THDP14Relay_log_info+0x25c)[0x813cbc]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_slave_sql+0xde9)[0x816dc9]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x123)[0xa224a3]
>   /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x91da)[0x7fb2739b11da]
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fb2730ec9cd]
>
> Trying to get some variables. Some pointers may be invalid and cause
>   the dump to abort. Query (7fb01c021a8a): is an invalid pointer
>   Connection ID (thread ID): 2 Status: NOT_KILLED
>
> The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html
>   contains information that should help you find out what is causing the
>   crash.

Comment: I would also start with memory testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped here was to downgrade back to 5.5 and let the slave run the queries it has been missing. Seems replication settings were lost so I had to restart the replication. Next step would be to upgrade the master and then slave accordingly. I assume the MySQL bug crashing it relates to wrong table format as this 5.6 replication has not been properly upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

When the problem is not related to the shared memory allocation, like in your case, good place to start is the mysql bug tracker, or, at least, their specialized community.

I would also advise you to:

- check your server's memory with [memtest86](http://www.memtest.org/)
- install and try more recent version of mysql 5.6.x server

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it's too general.